# SSRS returning zeros where Management Studio returns information

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssms

Within a query I have the following:

```
cast(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(cast([Commitment Amount] as nvarchar(15)), CHARINDEX('.', [Commitment Amount]), LEN([Commitment Amount])), '.', '.') as dec(2,2)) as cents
```

In management studio this will return information for example 0.39 on a row.  If I copy and paste the query into SSRS then it returns 0.00 for the same row that returned 0.39 in management studio.

***This is not a formatting issue. This happens when executing the query directly from the query designer in SSRS.***

Comment: have you attempted to hard code a value in for [Commitment Amount] and attempted to run it that way? if nothing else to at least see what it returns?

Comment: Good call.  When I hard code in [Commitment Amount] as 123456.99 it returns 0.99.

Comment: Went down a rabbit hole with [Commitment Amount] using cast and case statements but still no luck.  Still coming back as 0.00.

Comment: Nevermind we have a couple of test dbs.  I was running query in management studio against one and against another for ssrs.  UGH.

Comment: That will happen. The crazy things you come across when you start heading down  the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind we have a couple of test dbs. I was running query in management studio against one and against another for ssrs. UGH.